# use of Object instead of class in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am new to JavaScript and React. I am modifying the below code to use JavaScript objects instead of classes. I'm stuck because I don't understand the code in line 7, and why its throwing an error.

```js
import React from 'react';

function AwesomeComponent(props) {
    // instead of class AwesomeComponent exnteds React.Component
    AwesomeComponent = Object.assign(Object.create(React.Component.prototype))
    AwesomeComponent.props = props
    AwesomeComponent.state = { likesCount: 0 };
    this.onLike = this.onLike.bind(this);   // here's my problem. LINE 7

    onLike()
    let newLikesCount = this.state.likesCount + 1;
    this.setState({ likesCount: newLikesCount });

    AwesomeComponent.render = function() {
        return (
          <div>
            Likes : <span>{this.state.likesCount}</span>
            <div><button onClick={this.onLike}>Like Me</button></div>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AwesomeComponent;
```

Here is the error being thrown:

> ```
> AwesomeComponent.jsx:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onLike' of undefined
>     at AwesomeComponent (AwesomeComponent.jsx:7)
>     at ReactCompositeComponent.js:306
>     at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:75)
>     at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (ReactCompositeComponent.js:305)
>     at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:280)
>     at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:188)
>     at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:46)
>     at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:238)
>     at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (ReactDOMComponent.js:691)
>     at ReactDOMComponent.mountComponent (ReactDOMComponent.js:516)
> ```

Comment: can you paste the error you get?

Comment: AwesomeComponent.jsx:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onLike' of undefined
    at AwesomeComponent (AwesomeComponent.jsx:7)
    at ReactCompositeComponent.js:306
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:75)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (ReactCompositeComponent.js:305)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:280)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent  (ReactDOMComponent.js:516).....

Comment: if i use onLike(){} it throws error as well. unexpected token {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this**

```
   import React from 'react';

    class AwesomeComponent extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {likesCount : 0};
        this.onLike = this.onLike.bind(this);
      }

      onLike () {
        let newLikesCount = this.state.likesCount + 1;
        this.setState({likesCount: newLikesCount});
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            Likes : <span>{this.state.likesCount}</span>
            <div><button onClick={this.onLike}>Like Me</button></div>
          </div>
        );
      }

    }

    export default AwesomeComponent;
```

Comment: Thanks @mmk but I'm trying not to use class. is it not possible to use Object.create to mimic prototype inheritance in react?

Comment: i dont think so you can do that.